# Am having errors in inserting data to my data base

Tags: mysql

This is the MySQL code and it's getting some sort of errors about the `$`sign in the password position. And this password is auto-generated by Sha-MD5(PHP).

```
INSERT INTO
  user
SET
  full-name=John Doe,
  email=email@gmail.com,
  phone=12345678901,
  username=Mirror43,     
  password=$2y$10$OeNDS4hBqhNajGDhoLqqhOkXc1RXb.gI/bGWlgUOtxiac9lr.Fx0i,
  address=my street address,
  address2=fgffgfff,
  country=Nigeria,
  age=2020-06-04,
  fb_link=email@gmail.com,
  ref=email@gmail.com,
  image=1591624014_balaji-malliswamy-uU9ZPjNp0TY-unsplash.jpg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not valid SQL. You have to enclose strings (text) in quotes (`'John Doe'`) and `INSERT`s look like this:

```
insert into
  table
(
  column1,
  column2
)
values
(
  value_of_column_1,
  value_of_column_2
)
```

I don't know your PHP code but I think you should use [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) (docs for [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php), [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)).

I am not user of MySQL (I use PostgreSQL) but `user` is probably reserved name in MySQL. You have to enclose it in backticks (`` ` ``). You can even use this syntax on all table and column names.

---

After these modifications, your SQL should look like this:

```
INSERT INTO
  `user`
(
  `full-name`,
  `email`,
  `phone`,
  `username`,
  `password`,
  `address`,
  `address2`,
  `country`,
  `age`,
  `fb_link`,
  `ref`,
  `image`
)
values
(
  'John Doe',
  'email@gmail.com',
  12345678901, -- Use quotes if type of this column is text
  'Mirror43',     
  '$2y$10$OeNDS4hBqhNajGDhoLqqhOkXc1RXb.gI/bGWlgUOtxiac9lr.Fx0i',
  'my street address',
  'fgffgfff',
  'Nigeria',
  '2020-06-04',
  'email@gmail.com',
  'email@gmail.com',
  '1591624014_balaji-malliswamy-uU9ZPjNp0TY-unsplash.jpg' 
)
```